# Limitation of smart guide makes difficult to know distance between two lines in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Smart guide helps to put new objects or shapes in Adobe Illustrator, but unfortunately I am unable to know specific distance between two objects or shapes. In my case, to keep the same distance between two lines of flowchart, there is no solution. Is there any tool which measures the distance between two lines?

The red marked distance in below image could help to understand my issue.

Blessed to be part of this professional community of graphic design.

Thanking you in advance. [image: FlowChart without line distanceing]

Comment: Yes thare also is a tool that measures distance. That tool is the line tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try a different approach.  Enable the Grid and Snap to Grid instead. For example:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your help.